# How to remove an index in Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I have a space with some indexes and want to delete one of them.

I've overlooked the index's delete method in the documentation but get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method called `drop`:

```lua
box.space.test.index.user_id:drop()
```

Read more about [in documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_index/#lua-function.index_object.drop).